# Blank page arrange_ggsurvplots Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the function `arrange_ggsurvplots()` in order to have 4 `ggsurvplot()` in a 2x2 representation, but using this function, it builds a blank page before the plot of the 4 groups graphs.

I build 4 different survfit as:

```
library(survminer)


fit_1 <- survfit(Surv(...) ~ ..., data = data_1)
splots[[1]] <- ggsurvplot(fit_1,...)
```

In order to arrange it all:

```
arrange_ggsurvplots(splots, print = TRUE,
                ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the plot as an object, and then save it to disk with `ggsave()`:

```
myplots_out <- arrange_ggsurvplots(
  myplots,
  print = FALSE,
  ncol = 2,
  nrow = 2,
  title = "MySuperPlots")

ggsave(
  myplots_out,
  file = "Results/Survival.pdf",
  width = 10.5,
  height = 5)
```

That will avoid the production of the blank first page in the output file.

Comment: I think it is an issue with the package, according the manual, OP's code should work? (didn't test)